# Hide AppBarLayout and BottomNavigationView on single tap

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, bottomnavigationview

sorry for bad english

I have AppBarLayout, Webview and BottomNavigationView.

I want show/hide AppBarLayout and BottomNavigationView by single tap.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_chT"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar_chT"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
      app:title=""/>

  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


  <WebView
    android:id="@+id/textWebview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />


  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/button_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/webViewBackground"
    app:layout_behavior="BottomNavigationBehavior"
    app:menu="@menu/chapter_bottom"/>

  <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/webViewProgressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My custom BottomNavigationBehavior, but it hasn't good logic

```
class BottomNavigationBehavior<V : View>(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) :
        CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V>(context, attrs) {

    override fun layoutDependsOn(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, dependency: View): Boolean {
        if (dependency is Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) {
            updateSnackbar(child, dependency)
        }
        if (dependency is WebView) {
            updateWebView(child, dependency)
        }
        return super.layoutDependsOn(parent, child, dependency)
    }


    private fun updateSnackbar(child: View, snackbarLayout: Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) {
        if (snackbarLayout.layoutParams is CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) {
            val params = snackbarLayout.layoutParams as CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams

            params.anchorId = child.id
            params.anchorGravity = Gravity.TOP
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP
            snackbarLayout.layoutParams = params
        }
    }

    private fun updateWebView(child: View, webview: WebView) {

    }

}
```

For webview i have next code

```
textWebview.setOnTouchListener( object: OnSwipeTouchListener(applicationContext) {           

        override fun onTap() {
            if (appbar_chT != null) {
                val fullyExpanded = (appbar_chT!!.height - appbar_chT!!.bottom == 0) && (bottomNavigationView.height == bottomNavigationView.bottom - bottomNavigationView.top)

                appbar_chT?.setExpanded(!fullyExpanded)

                bottomNavigationView.updateView(fullyExpanded)

            }
        }
    })

private fun BottomNavigationView.updateView(fullyExpanded: Boolean) {
    if (fullyExpanded)
        this.animate().translationY(this.height.toFloat())
    else
        this.animate().translationY(0f)
}
```

So, it all works fine, but my problem is that i cant's see full text in WebView in "bars show" mode

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mMTK.png)
[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnUcK.png)

As you can see on images above, i can't see 19 and 20 strings because they are under bottom bar ( i can't scroll down webView anymore)

Could you give me some advices, or maybe there are another way to realise such functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I changed root layout to ConstraintLayout and used

```
 android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

with

```
visibility = View.GONE //or  
visibility = View.VISIBLE
```